# How to capture streaming output in python from subprocess.communicate()

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

Currently, I have something like this:

```
self.process = subprocess.Popen(self.cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = self.process.communicate()
```

The command I'm running streams the output, and I need the process to block before continuing.

How do I make it so that I can capture the streaming output AND have the streaming output printing through stdout? When I set `stdout=subprocess.PIPE`, I can capture the output, but it won't print the output. If I leave out `stdout=subprocess.PIPE`, it prints the output, but `communicate()` will return `None`.

Is there a solution that would do what I'm asking for WHILE providing blocking until the process is terminated/completed AND avoid buffer issues and pipe deadlock issues mentioned [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.wait)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can think of a few solutions.

#1: You can just go into the source to grab [the code for `communicate`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.3/Lib/subprocess.py#l881), copy and paste it, adding in code that prints each line as it comes in as well as buffering things up. (If its possible for your own `stdout` to block because of, say, a deadlocked parent, you can use a `threading.Queue` or something instead.) This is obviously a bit hacky, but it's pretty easy, and will be safe.

But really, `communicate` is complicated because it needs to be fully general, and handle cases you don't. All you need here is the central trick: throw threads at the problem. A dedicated reader thread that doesn't do anything slow or blocking between `read` calls is all you need.

Something like this:

```
self.process = subprocess.Popen(self.cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
lines = []
def reader():
    for line in self.process.stdout:
        lines.append(line)
        sys.stdout.write(line)
t = threading.Thread(target=reader)
t.start()
self.process.wait()
t.join()
```

You may need some error handling in the `reader` thread. And I'm not 100% sure you can safely use `readline` here. But this will either work, or be close.

#2: Or you can create a wrapper class that takes a file object and tees to `stdout`/`stderr` every time anyone `read`s from it. Then create the pipes manually, and pass in wrapped pipes, instead of using the automagic `PIPE`. This has the exact same issues as #1 (meaning either no issues, or you need to use a `Queue` or something if `sys.stdout.write` can block).

Something like this:

```
class TeeReader(object):
    def __init__(self, input_file, tee_file):
        self.input_file = input_file
        self.tee_file = tee_file
    def read(self, size=-1):
        ret = self.input_file.read(size)
        if ret:
            self.tee_file.write(ret)
        return ret
```

In other words, it wraps a file object (or something that acts like one), and acts like a file object. (When you use `PIPE`, `process.stdout` is a real file object on Unix, but may just be something that acts like on on Windows.) Any other methods you need to delegate to `input_file` can probably be delegated directly, without any extra wrapping. Either try this and see what methods `communicate` gets `AttributeException`s looking for and code those those explicitly, or do the usual `__getattr__` trick to delegate everything. PS, if you're worried about this "file object" idea meaning disk storage, read [Everything is a file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Everything_is_a_file) at Wikipedia.

#3: Finally, you can grab one of the "async subprocess" modules on PyPI or included in `twisted` or other async frameworks and use that. (This makes it *possible* to avoid the deadlock problems, but it's not *guaranteed*—you still have to make sure to services the pipes properly.)

Comment: how exactly would you implement #2? does a 'file' object indicate that I must write to disk (I'd prefer not to)?

Comment: @jaka: No, a pipe is already a file object. You're creating an object that wraps a file object, and delegates all file methods to it (except for `read`, which does a little extra around the delegated call).

Comment: I'll try to add at least some skeleton code to the first two answers.

Comment: I think threading is what I need. Thanks! Some skeleton code would be awesome as well! Once again, thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the code. Just a quick question -- if I replace `self.process.wait()` with `out, err = self.process.communicate()`, why does out have no output? Does the reader thread actually affect communicate()?

Comment: sorry to bother you again -- do you have any idea why reader doesn't run until the program is the process returns?

Comment: apparently `for line in self.process.stdout:` only gets run after the process returns. seems like `readline()` is the key

Comment: That surprises me a little bit. `for line in f:` should be the same as `while True:` `line = f.readline()` `if not line: break` for any reasonable file-like object, including the `process.stdout` pipe. But if for some reason it isn't, and you've got a workaround, I guess it isn't critical.

Comment: Can someone post a working example of solution #2 (or whichever is the easiest)? Something like :
import subprocess

process = subprocess.Popen("/bin/bash", shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE);

process.stdin.write("export MyVar=\"Test\"\n")
process.stdin.write("echo $MyVar\n")
process.stdin.flush()

stdout, stderr  = process.communicate()
print "stdout: " + str(stdout)

# Do it again
process.stdin.write("echo $MyVar\n")
process.stdin.flush()

stdout, stderr = process.communicate()
print "stdout: " + str(stdout)

Answer (score 2):

The output goes to your calling process, essentially capturing the `stdout` from `self.cmd`, so that output does not go anywhere else.

What you need to do is to print it from the 'parent' process if you want to see the output.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the whole point is that he wants to print it as it comes in—but his parent process is blocked until `communicate` returns, and therefore he can't print it from the parent process.