# Persistent subprocess.Popen session

Tags: python

I am trying to run a command, then later run another command in the same environment (say if I set an environment variable in the first command, I want it to be available to the second command). I tried this:

```
import subprocess

process = subprocess.Popen("echo \"test\"", shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE);

process.stdin.write("echo \"two\"\n")
process.stdin.flush()

stdout, stderr = process.communicate()
print "stdout: " + stdout
print "stderr: " + stderr
```

but the output is:

```
stdout: test

stderr:
```

Where I'd hope for it to be something like:

```
stdout: test
two

stderr:
```

Can anyone see what is wrong?

Comment: I just updated the answer with a pointer to the relevant question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are writing to the `stdin` of the process `echo`, which is not reading from its `stdin`, rather than to something like `bash` which continues to read `stdin`. To get the effect you want, look at the following code:

```
import subprocess
process = subprocess.Popen("/bin/bash", shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE);

process.stdin.write("echo \"test\"\n")
process.stdin.write("echo \"two\"\n")
process.stdin.flush()

stdout, stderr = process.communicate()
print "stdout: " + stdout
print "stderr: " + stderr
```

Output:

```
stdout: test
two

stderr:
```

Update: Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15654163/how-to-capture-streaming-output-in-python-from-subprocess-communicate) to resolve the streaming output issue.

Comment: That is much closer. Now if in between commands I want to get the output (I want the output of one command at a time), what would I do? communicate() seems to get the the end of the output so then I get a : ValueError: I/O operation on closed file (see edit)

Comment: You really should ask a second question for your second question, @DavidDoria, but the quick answer is that the whole point of `.communicate()` is to close `stdin`/`stdout`; you'll need to instead read/write to the handles in a loop and close manually when you're done.

Comment: @DavidDoria, I agree, that is technically a separate question, but if the linked question resolves your issue, it may save you the time of asking. :)

Comment: @merlin2011 Sorry guys, I'll move it. The linked question doesn't actually show how to do what they are suggesting, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @DavidDoria, Please accept this answer if it resolves the original issue, so that people are not confused.

Comment: @merlin2011 Sorry for the confusion. I accepted this answer, truncated the question to remove the second question, and moved it to here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23141676/get-the-output-of-multiple-commands-from-subprocess-popen